# Connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ be equipped with the subspace topology $T$ with respect to the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$. When is $X$ connected?

It's quite easy to see that if $X$ is an open interval $(a,b)$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ then it's connected. However, the lecture notes for my course says that $X$ is also connected if it's a closed interval $[a,b]$, a half open interval $[a,b)$ or a half open interval $(a,b]$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Suppose that $X$ is a half open interval $[a,b)$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, then wouldn't a valid separation of $X$ be $[a,c)$ and $[c,b)$ for $a \leq c \leq b$?

Comment: Is $[c,b)$ open in $X$ according to you, when $a<c$?

Comment: @B.Pasternak No, it's not. I realised it instantly when I saw your comment, I was just very sloppy when I thought about it before. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No. Open subsets of $[a,b)$ are open subsets of $\Bbb R$ intersected with $[a,b)$. And while $[a,c)$ is relatively open, $[c,b)$ is not. There is no open subset $U$ of $\Bbb R$ such that $U\cap[a,b)=[c,b)$, except for the trivial cases ($a=c$ or $b=c$).

Comment: Right, of course. I completely forgot what I was working with. Thanks